# How to use REST client from Play framework without Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I like the API from play framework for calling the RESTful API:

- [play.api.libs.ws.WS](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS%24.html)

Is there any way to use this API in a regular Scala project (not the Play project). What dependencies should I add to `build.sbt` to make it work? I know there are other libraries for building clients for REST, but I would like to use this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a dependency to Play!:

```
"com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.10" % "2.2.1"
```

You don't have to follow the Play! project convention to use the WebService. I wish it was possible to add only the WebService part as a standalone library but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: There were talks about it last year. At some point it might be possible.